# How to identify what is epic and story in splitting to features and pages?

Tags: jira

In my project I have serval pages such: home-page, blogs-list-page, blog-page, store-page, checkout-page, login-page, register-page, about-page.

I grouped the components into features:

- appcore -> will have about-page, home-page components.
- blogs -> will have blogs, blog, components.
- auth -> will have login-page and register-page components.
- store -> will have store-page and checkout-page components.

every page can use every component from every feature.
for example, the home-page can use login-page from the auth feature.

So how to build the epic and the story and the task in jira?

Did epic is a page?
Did feature is a story?
Task is "add button to login-page"?

How to identify what is epic and what is story and task in this scenario?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: So where I can ask this question?

Comment: @JonSud , I have written an answer , let me know if it helps. And if it helps , please upvote.

Answer (score 1):

**EPIC** - This can contain everything related to one particular functionality. Example Shopping Cart Page.

**Story** - This is a subset of EPIC. Means , it will have tasks like creating the UI for Cart Page. An API service to get the list of all items and show them in CART.
Update the Cart, if user adds an item to the cart. So, one story can consist of 3-4 front end and back end tasks. There can be one for designing db also.

And these stories can combine together to become one EPIC.

Comment: but in my case, feature are epics and story are tasks in the feature?